# Should We use entity without typeorm in nestJS, if we are using mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

So, I am not using TypeOrm but mongoose for mongodb.
The interfaces I create has no benefits for using Pipes because interface is typescript's behaviour and not Javascript's.

I have schema and Document but that too doesn't get into a lot of function arguments.
I get errors like

```
'UserDocument' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

(above UserDocument is created in the schema file with `export type UserDocument = User & Document;`)

What is the good practice if we are using mongoose ORM and the documents we make (with `export type UserDocument = User & Document;` or by making interfaces) are not available for most of the functions in nestJS.

Comment: Where are you using `UserDocument`? It's probably not what you're meaning to reference.

Comment: So should I create a new class with the same property as UserShema has, Isn't it  add too much redundant code for multiple schemas while using mongoose.

Comment: Would you like to recommend a good repository that follow good code practices in nestjs without using TypeORM. Or TypeORM is the most defacto thing that I should learn?

Comment: [I feel that Nest's docs show a good basic example](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb). TypeORM is... well it's something. I'd advise [MikroORM](https://github.com/mikro-orm/nestjs) or [Primsa](https://www.prisma.io/) over TypeORM though. But if you're working with Mongo, the `@nestjs/mongoose` package is good or using [`typegoose`](https://github.com/kpfromer/nestjs-typegoose) is good